# Active closure of server sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am having a small server (TCP server) which accepts at the max 10 connections on port 5000. I have created a socket in listen mode and accept connections.  When accept succeeds, I create a new thread and handle traffic in that thread. I have a client on the same machine which is able to connect and communicate with this server.

Now to understand TIME_WAIT, I kill my server application using ctrl+c. I expect to see the server sockets which were in "Established" state to be transferred to "TIME_WAIT". However, when I do netstat after the closure, I dont see a single socket in that "TIME_WAIT" state. I know that sockets in "listen" mode directly transition to CLOSED state. But I am confused why sockets returned by accept and currently in Established state are not in TIME_WAIT state.

(I am on a linux machine and tcp_fin_timeout value is set to 1min.)

My tcpdump looks like below:

```
localhost.49388 > localhost.5000:
    Flags [S], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0xaa93), seq 3264533269, win 32792,
    options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 20216234 ecr 0,nop,wscale 3], length 0              
localhost.5000 > localhost.49388:
    Flags [S.], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0xc6a0), seq 3352338762, ack 3264533270, win 32768,
    options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 20216234 ecr 20216234,nop,wscale 3], length 0
localhost.49388 > localhost.5000:
    Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x9fbe), ack 1, win 4099,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20216234 ecr 20216234], length 0           
localhost.5000 > localhost.49388:
    Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe42 (incorrect -> 0xa300), seq 1:27, ack 1, win 4096,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20216484 ecr 20216234], length 26           
localhost.49388 > localhost.5000:
    Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x9db0), ack 27, win 4099,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20216484 ecr 20216484], length 0          
localhost.49388 > localhost.5000:
    Flags [P.], cksum 0x0211 (incorrect -> 0x6be1), seq 1:1001, ack 27, win 4099,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20216484 ecr 20216484], length 1000              
localhost.5000 > localhost.49388:
    Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x91cb), ack 1001, win 6144,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20216484 ecr 20216484], length 0     
localhost.5000 > localhost.49388:
    Flags [R.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x8eeb), seq 27, ack 1001, win 6144,
    options [nop,nop,TS val 20217216 ecr 20216484], length 0
```

Comment: Have you tried it with clients on *other* machines?

Comment: No will check. Why would it be different?

Comment: I tried between two machines and tried the same procedure. Now I can see server sockets in TIME_WAIT. Why is this difference?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference unless you are running some hacked-up kernel. How do you run `netstat`?

Answer (score 0):

*But I am confused why sockets returned by accept and currently in Established state are not in TIME_WAIT state.*

Because you killed the process, preventing any kind of orderly shutdown.  You will see `TIME_WAIT` only if the process actually calls `close()` (or `shutdown()`) on a socket - which will send a `FIN` to the peer - and then remain alive long enough to receive both the `ACK` of the `FIN` sent to the peer and the peer's own `FIN` (for which an `ACK` will be sent back).  There are three ways to reach `TIME_WAIT`, one of them must happen for `TIME_WAIT` to be established, but that can only happen if the process is still alive for the transition to FIN_WAIT1 which is the start of all three paths.  Your Ctrl-C prevented even the `close()` that starts the sequence.

To see `TIME_WAIT`, you will have to arrange for your process to actively close a socket, e.g. in a handler installed for `SIGHUP`, or through some input mechanism.  Killing the process at any point is a good way to ensure not seeing what you want.

Comment: This is simply not true. TCP connection tear-down happens in the kernel, not in userland.

Comment: Of course.  And if you kill a process - as opposed to causing it to exit in an orderly fashion - anything sent from the other side will get a RST sent back.

Comment: Pull out `tcpdump` and trace a connection, `^C` one of the connected sides. You'll see a `FIN` sent out. In-kernel network stack does that for you (among other things).

Comment: @Nikoli: Yes, true. That is why I am expecting to see TIME_WAIT. I think any active close should end up in TIME_WAIT. If a server application is closed then kernel sends FIN which indirectly means server socket does active close and should end up in TIME_WAIT. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the kernel sends a courtesy FIN as part of process tear-down, the socket will *not* transition into FIN_WAIT1.  Even the ACK, from the other side, of that FIN will beget a RST!  The transition to FIN_WAIT1 requires a close()/shutdown() from the application level as the triggering event.  If a signal handler catches the SIGINT and calls exit(), that's good enough too.  But process termination via an uncaught signal is not.

Comment: @arayq2 There is no difference between the kernel sending a FIN and the application sending one. Both cause the port to transit the TCP state diagram in exactly the same way. If you want to continue maintaining the converse please provide a citation. Mine is RFC 793.

Comment: Who do I believe, you or my lying eyes? I see no TIME_WAIT, and I have a tcpdump where the ACK received for the FIN sent out begets a RST, as does the plaintive FIN from the other side after that.

Comment: @user2026599 Not any active close. An active close only ends up in TIME_WAIT if the host hasn't received a FIN on that port. See the [TCP state diagram, #3.5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt).

Comment: @arayq2 Evidence is one thing: explanation is another. Your explanation of your observations is not consistent with RFC 793; therefore it is incorrect.

Comment: If you are claiming that the socket will have transitioned into FIN_WAIT1 (because, evidently, a FIN was sent) then please explain why the treatment of the ACK and the subsequent FIN was a RST being sent in each case.

Comment: "Active close" is a neologism: RFC 793 doesn't use the term.  The transition diagram clearly marks two routes from the `ESTAB` state (page 22).  The one which people like to call "active close", leading to TIME_WAIT, is when a FIN is sent *before* one is received.

Comment: @EJP, please refer to the TCP state diagram.  Transitions are due to (state-changing) *events*.  Regardless of whether an event causes a change of state (it may not) some *action* will be taken.  In this sense, the *event* for the ESTAB -> FIN_WAIT1 transition is `app:close`, not `send:FIN`, which is simply an *action*.  What I have written is not in violation of RFC793.  It would be if sending the FIN were an event, but it is not.

Comment: @arayq2 It is me that is referring *you* to the TCP state diagram. Where in that does it distinguish between a close 'event' originating in the application and a close 'event' originating in the kernel? A. It doesn't. They are the same thing. If you have a citation for your claim please provide it. I've provided mine.

Comment: It doesn't so distinguish, because there is no relevant distinction.  The point is that application termination due to an uncaught signal will not generate the *event* necessary for the transition.

Comment: @arayq2, your given system might be a) mis-configured, b) running some non-standard, custom built kernel, c) something entirely different like an embedded OS with trimmed-down, hacked-up TCP/IP stack. We don't know. Check on a stock Linux or BSD kernel.

Comment: @EJP: On tcpdump, I am seeing a RST flag set and FIN is never sent. Something is broken badly. I am trying to figure out why my server is sending RST before FIN when I am testing the client and server on the same machine.

Comment: @arayq2 Make up your mind. If the distinction doesn't exist why are you talking about it? and if it does exist where is your normative reference? Where in RFC 793 does it allow the state changes after a FIN to be different depending on who issued it? You've been asked that enough times by now.