# server sending reset signal instead of FIN

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am learning tcp-ip stack, server-client connections. I wrote a simple client server. The client and servers were able to transfer data to each other without any issues. I am running client and server on the same machine. When I used to close the server with ctrl+c, I found kernel was sending RST signal instead of FIN. (Please refer my question: [Active closure of server sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737896/active-closure-of-server-sockets) )

With little more investigation, I realized one of my client was in read call and corresponding server thread was in infinite while loop doing nothing (Some buggy dumb coding on my part). But when I removed that infinite while loop, I saw expected behavior. I could see FIN being sent in both the directions.

So, I am wondering why tcp layer was sending RST in first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, you give up on waiting for the other end to accept the data.

Comment: If you see my tcpdump from the linked question, then there are no FIN packets. So, seems like server side socket never sent FIN

Comment: Eventually who gives up? And where is the evidence that the peer isn't accepting the data?

Comment: Eventually the side sending data gives up on attempting a graceful close. The peer wasn't accepting the data because it was trapped in an endless loop. At that point, the sending side will send a RST and the other side's read will return an error.

Comment: Why would being trapped in an endless loop in application mode affect what the kernel is and isn't able to do?

Comment: Because if the application is trapped in an endless loop, it can't receive data from the TCP connection. The kernel can't do a normal shutdown of the TCP connection until the application empties the receive buffer. Until that time, the application has the right to initiate an abnormal termination. If the other side times out before the application initiates a normal termination, then the other side will initiate an abnormal termination. (You don't longer on close forever. You give up if the other side's application doesn't read. See RFC1122, section 4.2.2.13.)

Comment: Short version: If one side of a TCP connection is sending data and the application on the other side doesn't read that data, if the sending side decides to try to close the connection normally, it can result in the TCP connection terminating abnormally. This is because the terminating side won't wait forever for the side that won't read the data and the TCP connection can't close normally until both applications read the data that was sent.

Comment: Shorter version: If the SRB is already full, the FIN can never even be sent let alone acknowledged?

Comment: Thanks EJP and David!!!! I was finding difficult to get a reason behind the issue. What you said completely make sense.